# Substitute for the PNP D45H11 transistor?

Tags: transistors, robotics

I'm starting the course on edX: "Introduction to Control System Design-Computational State Space Approaches" Link: (https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-state-space-control-mitx-6-302-1x). The course outline involves the construction and control of a propeller levitated arm using state space methods, but the problem is that I just can't find all the components they require, so I'm looking for good substitutes. Especially for one of the transistors, the D45H11. Any tips?

Comment: It's just a PNP power BJT for common usage. V_CEO is 80V. But you can get that or more, pretty commonly (TIP32C.) Have you done a basic search for a power PNP in a TO-220 package and looked at a few datasheets, yet? (Class looks interesting, by the way!)

Comment: The part is easily available. The most  common jellybean part that is similar (TIP32C) has inferior gain (especially at higher currents) and might cause problems.

Comment: Just saying, it's pretty common online. http://au.element14.com/fairchild-semiconductor/d45h11/transistor/dp/1611595?mckv=sIhBpSZ4t%7Cpcrid%7C96154352448&CMP=KNC-GAU-GEN-SKU-G30-FAI

Comment: If there are many parts you need to substitute it may make sense to order from one of the larger suppliers. Typically they can be quite a bit cheaper than local stores and you can usually get more obscure parts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'll write an answer. (Actually, you have some good clues already.)

One place to go is to [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com). They have a reasonably complete search engine for questions like this. I plugged in *transistor* in the search bar and got a nice dialog thing where I could plug in \$I_C\$ and select some gain values and plug in a minimum \$V_{CEO}\$ value, as well. Plus the TO-220 packaging (there are nearby packages, but why not make it exact?) I also added the *in-stock* choice. (If Digikey isn't carrying it, then perhaps you shouldn't consider attempting to use it, either.)

Of course, the D45H11 popped right up and from several sources, too. (As it should.) It's cheap and they have them in stock for about $1 each. I don't know why you can't get them. I'd just order them, in your shoes. But there is another option that popped up (other than a near look-alike from OnSemi called MJF45H11G.) It's the Fairchild BDX34C, which is still cheaper yet. So if you really can't consider the D45H11 for some reason, then take a look at the datasheet for the BDX34B or BDX34C ([here](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BD/BDX34C.pdf)) and see if you think it might be okay to substitute. It's 76 cents, too. (I'm not going to walk down the parameter list for you -- you can ask if you have a question, later.)